# error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token

Tags: c, struct

Why this error is popping up (for int index = -1). Here's the segment of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define Offset 12

int num_frames;

struct node
    {
        struct node* next;
        long data;
    };

struct page
{
    int index = -1;
    int frame = -1;
    int dirty = 0; //0 is clean, 1 is dirty
    int valid = 0; //0 is not, 1 is valid
    int referenced = 0; //0 is not, 1 is referenced
};
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: you cannot initialize struct members in the declaration. That syntax (tho maybe useful) does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in

```
struct page
{
    int index = -1;
    int frame = -1;
    int dirty = 0; //0 is clean, 1 is dirty
    int valid = 0; //0 is not, 1 is valid
    int referenced = 0; //0 is not, 1 is referenced
};
```

You define a new type `struct page` and try to initialize it at the same declaration. Types don't have default values. The right way to do it is to define the new type `struct page` without initial values, and then initiate a new `struct page` variable with those values.